# Symfony / Twig Variable "replaceString" does not exist

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I don't understand why he can't find my variable then what is well defined.

My error :

Variable "replaceString" does not exist.

```
in templates/scraping/index.html.twig (line 5)

{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block bodyIndex %}
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">        
         {% for rS in replaceString %}            
             <li class="list-group-item">{{ rS }}</li>        
         {% endfor %}
   </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Controller:

```
class ScrapingController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/scraping", name="scraping")
     */
    public function getMovie()
    {

        $client = new Client();

        $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://www.torrents9.cc/torrents_films.html,trie-seeds-d');

        // On filtre sur les éléments pour les récuperer
        $crawler->filter('tbody > tr > td > a')->each(function ($node) {

            // On remplace les strings en trop par une chaine vide avec str_replace
            $emptyString = array("FRENCH", "TS", "DVDRIP", "WEBRIP", "TRUEFRENCH", "TRUE", "PROPER");
            $replaceString = str_replace($emptyString, "",$node->text()."\n");

            return $this->render('scraping/index.html.twig', array(
                'replaceString' => $replaceString
            ));
        });

        return $this->render('scraping/index.html.twig', [
            'crawlers' => $crawler
        ]);

    }

}
```

Twig:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block bodyIndex %}
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        {% for rS in replaceString %}
            <li class="list-group-item">{{ rS }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

I'd like to post in twig a list of movies I'm retrieving from another website

Thanks.

Comment: It is not defined in the last return of your controller you only supply a crawlers variable to twig

Comment: If I add the replaceString variable in the last render, it displays me error message : 
Notice: Undefined variable: replaceString                                                                            return $this->render('scraping/index.html.twig', [
            'crawlers' => $crawler,
            'replaceString' => $replaceString
        ]);

Comment: Can you show me how you would have done it, please?

Comment: Try `return $this->render('scraping/index.html.twig', [ 'crawlers' => $crawler, 'replaceString' => [] ]);` instead. Since replaceString is not defined outside the if, it's not available in the second return statement.

Comment: even if I add in my return: 
 $this->render('scraping/index.html.twig', ['crawlers' => $crawler,'replaceString' => [] ] );

I still have the same mistake.

Comment: The same mistake? Or is the error gone and you're just not getting data?  Because if you copied that verbatim you copied an empty array

Comment: I had to copy an empty board... But I don't know what to put in my painting? 

['crawlers' => $crawler, replaceString' => [??????] ]);

Answer (score 1):

change your controller to look like this.

```
class ScrapingController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/scraping", name="scraping")
     */
    public function getMovie()
    {

        $client = new Client();
        $replaceString = array();

        $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://www.torrents9.cc/torrents_films.html,trie-seeds-d');

        // On filtre sur les éléments pour les récuperer
        $crawler->filter('tbody > tr > td > a')->each(function ($node) {

            // On remplace les strings en trop par une chaine vide avec str_replace
            $emptyString = array("FRENCH", "TS", "DVDRIP", "WEBRIP", "TRUEFRENCH", "TRUE", "PROPER");
            $replaceString[] = str_replace($emptyString, "",$node->text()."\n");

        });

        return $this->render('scraping/index.html.twig', [
            'crawlers' => $crawler,
            'replaceString' => $replaceString
        ]);

    }

}
```